# Codename one MediaPlayer doesn't release video on form change

Tags: codenameone

I have an app with a form that shows a list of items. When you click on an item it shows a new form with a video. After pressing back to go to the list of items, then going into a new item, the old video from the first form is still playing.

I've tried, removing video components, setting media and media player to null, revalidating things. No idea how it keeps hold of the old media. If I try and do media.cleanup() in the back method I get:
 java.lang.NullPointerException - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.VideoView.isPlaying()' on a null object reference

Here is my code on back:

```
Command back = new Command("Back") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            imageVideoContainer.removeAll();
            if (previousForm == null) {
                previousForm = new PoleBookMain();
            }
            previousForm.showMainForm();
        }
    };
```

Then the showMainForm method is:

```
public void showMainForm() {
    current = form;
    form.show();
    current.revalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `pause()` and `cleanup()` to completely remove the media if you no longer need it and it is still playing.

Comment: @toby-mundy you need to use comments not try to edit answers. If you had an issue/regression I suggest filing a new question and going into detail elaborating on the platform where this worked/failed and ideally a good timeline of when something might have regressed so we can track it down

Comment: Sorry for slow response. But calling pause() and cleanup() doesn't make any difference. That was the code I originally had, which stopped working.

Comment: It's possible that this is a regression from the new peer component support. If you target version 3.5 are you seeing this issue?